# PC uses on-board graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

My build is this

Motherboard : G41MXE Foxconn

CPU : Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650

GPU : Nvidia Geforce 560Ti

OS : Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

On Board Graphics : Intel G41 Express Chipset

My pc uses the on-board graphics instead of the gpu. I tried changing the settings in the bios to PEG/IGD (to change the priority) but when I do this I only get a blackscreen (doesn't matter if I plug into the mobo or gpu, both show black screen when I do this change). The gpu fans spin, plus I have connected all the pcie plugs. (I tested it with an older card too, but still the same thing) I have the latest bios flashed (since I thought it was a bios problem). Also I tried resetting the CMOS.

Comment: Do you get any output during POST from the graphics card (esp when set to PCI Express Graphics/IntegratedGD)? does the card work in another desktop? (just to make sure the card is fine, the cables are fine and that the monitor connected to that cable is not locked on another input). If you do get output from the BUIS during POST but not once windows is loaded then that would also be nice to add.

Comment: no I dont get any output during the post and yes everything has been tested on my main pc. The gpu runs fine on my other motherboard.